# Where can I download Spring Framework jars without using Maven?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

SpringSource.org changed their site to http://spring.io

Does someone know how to get the latest build without Maven/github? from http://spring.io/projects

Comment: To me, this question is not off-topic. The answer of fujy helped me finding exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Reopened. I think the point of confusion here comes from folks not realizing that spring.io *does not make it easy to just download this stuff!* I don't know why - maybe they just love Maven more than they love folks using Spring. But regardless, this is an actual problem being faced by folks trying to work with this stuff.

Answer (score 226, accepted):

### Please edit to keep this list of mirrors current

I found this `maven` repo where you could download from directly a `zip` file containing all the jars you need.

- https://maven.springframework.org/release/org/springframework/spring/
- https://repo.spring.io/release/org/springframework/spring/

### Alternate solution: Maven

The solution I prefer is using `Maven`, it is easy and you don't have to download each `jar` alone. You can do it with the following steps:

1. Create an empty folder anywhere with any name you prefer, for example `spring-source`
2. Create a new file named `pom.xml`
3. Copy the xml below into this file
4. Open the `spring-source` folder in your console
5. Run `mvn install`
6. After download finished, you'll find spring jars in `/spring-source/target/dependencies`

   ```
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
     <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
     <groupId>spring-source-download</groupId>
     <artifactId>SpringDependencies</artifactId>
     <version>1.0</version>
     <properties>
       <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
     </properties>
     <dependencies>
       <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
         <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
       </dependency>
     </dependencies>
     <build>
       <plugins>
         <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>2.8</version>
           <executions>
             <execution>
               <id>download-dependencies</id>
               <phase>generate-resources</phase>
               <goals>
                 <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
               </goals>
               <configuration>
                 <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dependencies</outputDirectory>
               </configuration>
             </execution>
           </executions>
         </plugin>
       </plugins>
     </build>
   </project>
   ```

---

Also, if you need to download any other spring project, just copy the `dependency` configuration from its corresponding web page.

For example, if you want to download `Spring Web Flow` jars, go to its [web page](http://projects.spring.io/spring-webflow/), and add its `dependency` configuration to the `pom.xml` `dependencies`, then run `mvn install` again.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-webflow</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I liked the way you downloaded spring jars. but `/spring-source/target/dependencies` contains only 7 jar files.
How can i download all jars?

Comment: The latest Spring 3.2.7 is not there.

Comment: Simply use the `maven install` method, here is the pom.xml for downloading it http://pastebin.com/n1aNbNXf

Comment: great except the maven site is blocked as a "security risk". What then?

Comment: @lonstar .. you can also try the other site that is provided in other answers here http://repo.spring.io/release/org/springframework/spring/

Comment: FYI: I've converted this to a wiki to encourage folks to keep it updated (and prevent the question from being closed or deleted until such a time as Spring gets their act together and makes this more obvious).

Comment: `Open the spring-source folder in your console` Can you tell what console you're referring to here? I'm not from JAVA background so this is all new to me.

Comment: @asprin Any console where you have access to `mvn` commands (e.g., Bash terminal, Windows cmd, eclipse terminal, .... )

Comment: @asprin Here is an example for how to access maven from Windows cmd https://howtodoinjava.com/maven/how-to-install-maven-on-windows-7/

Comment: This does not work.  I get build error:  Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:jar:2.8: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:pom:2.8 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)