# How To Download Spring Framework

Tags: spring

I am trying to download spring framework for my java application in this https://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/ site, but the problem is that there is no option for the download.

Can anyone help please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I download Spring Framework jars without using Maven?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19082860/where-can-i-download-spring-framework-jars-without-using-maven)

Answer (score 10):

Just download the latest zip version from https://repo.spring.io/release/org/springframework/spring/ .Then unzip it and add jars from it to your project

Answer (score 3):

Select which modules you need and generate an initial project in https://start.spring.io/

Answer (score 2):

your question is not correct!
because you need a Layer such as Maven or Gradle !
but if you need to spring library . you can download it from this way:

you can use this web site For any framework  such as spring:
https://jar-download.com/artifacts/org.springframework/spring-core

Answer (score 0):

There is already an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19812945/3975504) to your question.

But if you are using maven or gradle (Dependency Management tools), you have the snippets needed to use Spring Framework on the site you provided. Just add these to your dependencies:

**MAVEN:**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**GRADLE**

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-context:4.3.2.RELEASE'
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can download latest version from here.
https://repo.spring.io/ui/native/release/org/springframework/spring/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29799628)